Solving an inhomogeneous ODE using Green’s functions
I'm trying to solve the following ODE using Green's function
$$ y''(x) + 4y(x) = e^{x/2}$$
with the following boundary conditions:
$$ y(0) = y(\pi / 4 ) = 0 $$
So I start by solving the homogenous part:
$$ y_h'' + 4y_h = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad y_h = Asin(2x) + B\cos(2x) $$
Applying Boundary conditions:
$$ y_h(0) = B = 0 $$
$$ y_h(\pi/4) = A\sin(\pi/2) = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad A=0 $$
So $ y_h(x) =0 $.
Now using Green's function to find the particular solution, our differential operator is:
$$ L = \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + 4 $$
So we get
$$  \frac{d^2G}{dx^2} + 4G(x,s) = 0 $$
Now we get the following solutions on the right and left of $s$:
$$ G_L (x,s) = A\sin(2x) + B\cos(2x) $$
$$ G_R (x,s) = C\sin(2x) + D\cos(2x) $$
Applying Boundary conditions:
$$ G_L (0,s) = B = 0 $$
$$ G_R (\pi/4,s) = C\sin(\pi /2) = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad C = 0 $$
So we are left with:
$$ G_L (x,s) = A\sin(2x)  $$
$$ G_R (x,s) = D\cos(2x) $$
Now we apply the continuity condition at $x=s$:
$$ G_R(x=s,s) - G_L(x=s,s) = 0 \quad \rightarrow \quad D\cos(2s) - A\sin(2s) = 0 $$
and the discontinuity of the derivatives:
$$ G_R'(x=s,s) - G_L'(x=s,s) = \frac{1}{p(s)} = 1 $$
$$ \rightarrow -2D\sin(2s) - 2A\cos(2s) = 1 $$
And here is where I get stuck because I can't solve for A and D and clearly I did something wrong along the way? Thought that a second eye may help! Thanks in advance!

Why using such a complicated method ?
Your equation is linear with constant coefficients, so it is sum of a general solution of homogenous equation $A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)$ and one particular solution with RHS.
The roots you have found for the characteristic homogeneous equation are $\pm 2i$ resulting in $e^{\pm 2ix}$ terms.
Your RHS is $e^{\frac 12 x}$ with a root $\frac 12$ which does not conflicts with $\pm 2i$ therefore you can search for a particulation solution of the form $Ce^{\frac 12 x}$.
Reporting in the ODE gives $C=\frac 4{17}$

Therefore $y(x)=A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)+\frac 4{17}e^{\frac x2}$

Note: you need to apply initial conditions to this final $y(x)$ NOT to the solution of the homogeneous equation as you did.

Generally speaking when solving linear ODE

the full equation has a RHS of the form $P(x)e^{rx}$ with $P$ polynomial.
your homogeneous equation has root $r$ with multiplicity $m$  ($0$ by convention if not a root)

Then you need to search for a particular solution in the form $Q(x)e^{rx}$ with $Q$ polynomial and $$\deg(Q)=\deg(P)+m$$

I'm trying to practice solving ODE's using Green's function so thats way I choose to go the hard way!:D But now I have the correct answer to check my solution, appreciate your help:)

In constructing the Green's function, you got to a linear system
$$
DC-AS=0,
DS+AC=-\frac12,
$$
where $C^2+s^2=1$. This kind of rotation is easy to invert, giving
$$
D=-\frac12S,\\
A=-\frac12D.
$$
From there you get the full form of the Green's function
$$
G(x,s)=-\frac12\sin(2\min(x,s))\cos(2\max(x,s)).
$$
To evaluate the resulting integrals you need to use either 2x2 partial integration or use the complex forms of sine and cosine to get integrals of exponential functions.
